# Linux docker images on SF windows

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric

Can linux docker images be deployed on service fabric on windows? What are the steps to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, at this time running Linux containers on Windows based clusters is [not supported](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-containers/issues/2).